# Can't install Google USB drivers for Kazam 348 on WIndows 10

Tags: android, windows, usb, driver, windows-10

I tried to install the Google USB drivers needed for Android development on my Windows 10 PC. But for some unknown reason it fails.

The phone (Kazam Tornado 348)ships with an option to enable the phone as a virtual CD ROM. When I do so I can se an "Install" file that should install the needed drivers. However they fail without any further details.

I then wrote a mail to Kazam and asked the for new drivers - however they say that they do NOT have any drivers and I should ask Google !!!!! Funny !

On Googles development site I downloaded the "generic" USB drivers. They install but I can't update my Tornado 348 driver through the device manager. It simply says that no valid drivers was found.

I also looked through the list of OEM suppliers - but Kazam is no listed.

One final notice - I can see that the drivers supplied on the Virtual CD ROM is from Media Tek. Also think they supplied the CPU in the phone. But searching their homepage for a driver not give me any result.

Anyone else out there with a Kazam Tornado 348 that is working in Windows 10? 
The USB actually work - but is marked with a yellow exclamation mark. So I can see the phone in the file explorer. But in the device manager I can see that there is a problem - and also in Visual Studio it will not show as a device I can use for testing my code.

Answer (score 4):

BLU VIVO AIR had same issue.

Use a USB cable to connect the Windows PC and your phone . Open up Device manager. You'll see the your phone show up in "Other Devices" as unavailable.

Download and install the Google Generic USB Driver from http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html#top . Note down and remember the location where you install the google driver to.

Right mouse your phone select Update Driver Software…

Select "Browse for driver software on your computer"

Navigate to where you installed the Google USB Driver software

Select "Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer"

Select "Show all devices"

Select "Have Disk"

Navigate to where you installed the Google USB driver, select the android_winusb.inf file

In the Update Driver Software - YOUR PHONE dialog select "Android ADB Interface"

Ignore the "Update Driver Warning" message.

You will now see the Android Device -> Android ADB Interface in Device Manager, and VIVO AIR will be gone from "Other Devices". You should now also be able to turn on things like USB/Mass Storage Mode on the phone so you can view files from Windows Explorer as well as debug to the device.

I blogged about getting the generic google usb driver to install here with step by step and no funny links or ads - http://www.devfish.net/post/2015/07/20/android-usb-adb-drivers-for-blu-phones-vivo-air.aspx .

Comment: Thank you! Fantastic explanation.